# Liferea don't read RSS feed when I've changed the pubDate

Tags: php, mysql, date, rss

I have [rss](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/comments-rss.php) and I needed to recreate mysql function for pubdate, it look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rss_date(date datetime)
RETURNS VARCHAR(30) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN DATE_FORMAT(date, "%a, %d %b %T UTC");
```

and the output look like this:

```
<pubDate>Mon, 07 Oct 09:05:24 UTC</pubDate>
```

I don't remember how my rss_date function look like before because it was removed. What's wrong with that RSS and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSS datetime standard is `D, d M Y H:i:s O`. In MySQL format is `'%a, %d %b %Y %T ___` (where `___` is timezone, offset `+0200` or shortcut like `UTC`, `EST` etc. are valid).

More about date-time syntax for RSS feeds can be read in [RFC-822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), section 5.

```
DROP FUNCTION `RSS_DATE`;

CREATE FUNCTION `RSS_DATE` (date DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(31) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%a, %d %b %Y %T UTC');

SELECT RSS_DATE(NOW()); # will output > Tue, 08 Oct 2013 18:48:56 UTC
```

For validating feed you can use [Feed Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/feed/).

Comment: Now I see it, I forget about the year.